# Passing data from from to subform not working properly in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Main Form (frmPurchases) with a SubForm (subfrmPurchases). The field UPC on the SubForm is a combo box with 2 columns, one numeric (the Product ID) and the other text. I have a Not-In-List event to open a separate form to add the new product. The following lines of code is executed after the product details has been entered.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
On Error GoTo errline

If IsFormLoaded("frmPurchases") = True Then
    Forms!frmPurchases!subfrmPurchases.Form!UPC.Undo
    Forms!frmPurchases!subfrmPurchases.Form!UPC.Requery
    Forms!frmPurchases!subfrmPurchases.Form!UPC = Me.UPC
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "ADDPRODUCT", acSaveYes
    Forms!frmPurchases!subfrmPurchases.Form!Quantity.SetFocus
Else
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "ADDPRODUCT", acSaveYes
End If

errline:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

What is happening:

-The product is successfully added

-On the SubForm field UPC, the product is there (because I've set it up so that you cannot move to a new record in the SubForm leaving that field empty) but the combo box is shown blank.

-On the record source for subfrmPurchases (the Purchases table) the Product ID is shown together with all the data entered in subfrmPurchases.

Why is the combo box not refreshing to show the newly added product ie the text column of the combo box?

EDIT: Ok so I figured this out. I forgot to mention that the combo box UPC was not being filled with data in the normal way. I was using a Class to call the row source, so I needed to reference the Method within the class to Requery the combo box.

Comment: Try changing `!UPC` to `.UPC`. Same for Quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the combobox *bound value* (Product ID), not the displayed text (UPC). So:

```
Forms!frmPurchases!subfrmPurchases.Form!UPC.Value = Me!ProductID.Value
```